# error : Internal Server Error Laravel 5.4 ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Using following ajax call to retrieve parameter in controller but it gives the error. The happened when I have added parameter `id` in ajax and controller.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/delprofile',
    type: 'delete',
    data: {  
       id: 5,
       '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(){ alert("Record deleted.") },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Laravel Function:

```
Route::delete('/delprofile','ProfileController@delprofile');

public function delprofile (Request $request){
   $id=$request->input('id');
   DB::table('education')->where('id','=',id)->delete();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest it may be a problem in the laravel part of the function. Maybe check if `$id` is actually populated first?

Comment: @Deckerz how to check as I'm passing static value from ajax meanwhile.

Comment: Try just outputting it to the error log in PHP and just have a look if 5 is actually logged. If it is working the error must be in the DB query.

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **id** is a variable, `$id` instead of `id`

**Also, for a better code:**

1- You specify the method in your AJAX call as a standard `"POST"`

2- you add this to your data: `_method: 'delete'` since that's the recommended way to send **DELETE**,**PATCH** and **PUT** requests to Laravel.

3- add a `return response()->json($id);` to make sure the ID has been sent successfully.

4- in your success function, console.log the ID `success: function(data){console.log(data); alert("Record deleted.")....`

Comment: did you try to give ur route a name and output it directly in the JS? like `url:'{{route('delprofile')}}'` after the route becomes: `Route::delete('/delprofile','ProfileController@delprofile')->name('delprofile');` in case you have the script inside a blade template

Comment: the issue comes when I have added parameter `id` otherwise it working fine

Comment: check the edited answer, its because of your id! it should be a variable!!